# Powershell: view remote computer current user certificate

Tags: powershell

I am trying to view through PowerShell remote computer, current user certificate.
Something like `Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My` but for remote computer if a user is login as admin

Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: Take a look at this website: https://www.powershellbros.com/powershell-tip-of-the-week-get-certificate-remotely/

Comment: I did check the website, but it is only giving local machine, I am trying remotely retrieve user certificate

Comment: Note that SO has rules: [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) PS only runs in the user context of the person that started it. You cannot natively use Powershell to run as the logged-on user. It's a Windows security boundary. You need to use 3rdP tools, like PSExec to do this sort of thing. There are modules in teh powershellgallery.com that talk to the run as remote user thing.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried invoke-command?

```
invoke-command <computername> {get-childitem cert:\currentUser\my}
```

You can also pass a cred through if needed.

```
Invoke-Command <computername> -Credential (Get-Credential) {Get-ChildItem cert:\currentUser\my}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple `invoke-command` to get the details from remote computers provided you have PSRemoting configured properly.

The same command that you are using can be used inside the `Invoke-Command` to fetch the details:

```
$Servers = "Comp1",
           "Comp2"
 
  $Results = @()
  $Results = Invoke-Command -cn $Servers {
          $Certs = @{} | Select Certificate,Expired
          $Cert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\My | Where-Object {$_.subject -match [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("computername")}
          If($Cert){
              $Certs.Certificate = $Cert.subject
              $Certs.Expired = $Cert.NotAfter
          }
          Else{
              $Certs.Certificate = " - "
              $Certs.Expired = " - "
          }
          $Certs
  } | Select-Object @{n='ServerName';e={$_.pscomputername}},Certificate,Expired
```

Powershell Bros and galley has lot of similar examples to do this sort of work.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question correctly, you want to get the certificate of the current user, from a remote session. This is entirely possible, assuming you create this remote session as the user in question. Let's say that your username is *ADVIR*, and mine is *PowerShellGuy*, and you're trying to get the my current user cert from *machine1*.

```
$userWeWantCertFrom = "PowerShellGuy"

# This will prompt you for the credentials
$creds = get-credential -UserName $userWeWantCertFrom -Message "Enter password for $userWeWantCertFrom"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName "machine1" -Credential $creds -Scriptblock {
    Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\My
}
```